# JQuery; toggle hide show effects all! How to prevent?

Tags: jquery, hide, toggle, show

With my 'add a box' button, a box is added.
With append! you append some elements to the box (.togglecontainer) to be exact
With the show more/show les button i want the whole togglecontainer beneath
that button, to toggle hide and show.

I understand why all containers with that classname start to toggle, but i only want the container beneath its togglebutton to toggle.

I tried this code wich didn't work properly;

```
$('.togglebtn').toggle(function() {
    $('.togglecontainer').hide();       
    $(this).html('Show less');
}, function() {
    $('.togglecontainer').show();
    $(this).html('Show more');
});
```

Can anyone explain me and help me how to make that work?
Thanks in advance!

Here is my code; 
http://jsfiddle.net/2LTd9/

Comment: Wait a minute, toggle doesn't accept two callbacks. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a scope selector.
Try this:

```
$('.togglebtn').toggle( function() {              
 $('.togglecontainer', this).hide();                     
 var txt = $(this).html();
 $(this).html((txt=='Show less')?'Show more':'Show less');      
});
```

EDIT: Updated the code as per OP's inputs @ jsfiddle.

Updated the code and posted @ http://jsfiddle.net/Chandu/PtwWD/2/
Check it and let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you Cybernate, it doesnt seem to toggle the visibility yet it does toggle between html Show less /Show more

Comment: @ Cybernate i appreciate your help, but it doesnt work properly look;
http://jsfiddle.net/PtwWD/

Comment: @Cybernate Yes thank you so much, just one more thing; when you click add a box, it starts with hiding immediatly, but its okay to start 'shown' when 'add a box' is clicked

Comment: Updated the code at jsFiddle (one change to CSS and one to JS). Check it now http://jsfiddle.net/Chandu/PtwWD/4/

Answer (score 1):

`toggle()` does not accept two callback functions.

Have a read of the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for more information on how to use toggle.